# Java: verify if a string is formed only by letters from another string

Tags: java, string, character

I want to make a function who have String a and String b. I want to verify if String a is formed only by characters/letters from String b.

Ex:

```
    String a="abz";
    String b="abecxe";
```

The result is false, because String b is not contain 'z' from String a.

Thank you!

Comment: Put the characters in a set and check if all characters in the set from a are in the set from b

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can write code to protect against null/invalid input:

```
return b.replaceAll("["+a+"]", "").length() == 0;
```

As pointed out this will fail for arbitrary Strings.

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
    if (!a.contains(b.substring(i, i + 1)) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Again, you write the validation.

Comment: Fair enough; I was focused on "letters" rather than any characters, based on his example.

Answer (score 0):

One very straightforward way to do this is to write a method that converts a `String` into a set of characters, then take advantage of the `removeAll` method of the `Set` interface.  You might need the Apache `ArrayUtils` class to convert the `char[]` from your `String` into a `Character[]`.

It could look like this.

```
public static boolean containsOnlyCharactersFrom(String first, String second) {
    return charactersIn(first).removeAll(charactersIn(second)).isEmpty();
}

private static Set<Character> charactersIn(String argument) {
    Character[] characterArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(argument.toCharArray());
    return new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(characterArray));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all!

i solve the problem with String matching(i tried this method in the past but i was wrong):

```
     if ( a.matches("[" + b + "]+")) {
                      label1.setText("The String a contains only letters from String b!");
                  } else {
                      label2.setText("The String a contains more letters than String b!");
                  }
```